# Dalek.js not setting element values

Tags: dalekjs

Trying to use the .type action fails. This is on a web app using angular, not sure if this is related to it.

I can get assert attributes and existence of elements, but trying to use .type or .setValue fails

Here is the test

```
module.exports = {
  'Smoke test app.ablio': function (test) {
test
  .open('http://app.ablio.com')
  .assert.title().is('ablio :: Communication Without Barriers', 'Title OK')
  .open('https://app.ablio.com/signin')
  .assert.attr('#sign-in', 'type', 'submit', "submit signin form exists")
  .assert.exists('#username', "username form field exists")
  .assert.attr('#username', 'type', 'text', "username form field is type text")
  .assert.exists('#password', "password form field exists")
  .assert.attr('#password', 'type', 'password',"password form field is type password")
  .type('#username', 'testuser')
  .assert.val('#username', 'testuser', 'Username was entered')
  .screenshot ('shots/final.png')
  .done(); 
   }
 };
```

the assert.val() fails:

Output:

```
dalek smoketest.js 
Running tests
Running Browser: PhantomJS
OS: mac 10.10 (Yosemite) 32bit
Browser Version: 1.9.8

 RUNNING TEST - "Smoke test app.ablio"
▶ OPEN http://app.ablio.com
✔ TITLE Title OK
▶ OPEN https://app.ablio.com/signin
✔ ATTRIBUTE submit signin form exists
✔ EXISTS username form field exists
✔ ATTRIBUTE username form field is type text
✔ EXISTS password form field exists
✔ ATTRIBUTE password form field is type password
▶ TYPE #username
✘ VAL
0 EXPECTED: testuser
0 FOUND: 
0 MESSAGE: Username was entered
▶ SCREENSHOT shots/final.png
✘ TEST - "Smoke test app.ablio" FAILED

 6/7 assertions passed. Elapsed Time: 8.55 sec
```

DalekJS CLI Tools Version: 0.0.5
DalekJS  local install: 0.0.9

Comment: OK, so after a few debugging sessions, I can see that Dalek only sees the first DOM loaded and not the DOM loaded by angular. Is there any way to wait for angular to load the DOM?

Comment: This resolves the issue and provides support for angular: https://gist.github.com/ryanzec/7546175

Answer (score 0):

This resolves the issue and provides support for angular: http://gist.github.com/ryanzec/7546175

Answer (score 0):

Scanned the DOM of the page & there you´ll see that you have 2 inputs with the id of `username`. That for one thing is invalid, and second, the `username` you´re are trying to fill is the 2nd in the DOM hierarchy. If it would be the first, it would even work, regardless of the invalid DOM.

I don't think that this is an Angular specific thing, as I have a hard time to believe that Angular itself would generate invalid DOM.

Comment: I corrected the double id and that did not help. because the second input is not generated on the first DOM load, but by angular.

 But after using ryanzec action .waitFor(scripts.angular) (http://gist.github.com/ryanzec/7546175), it works as expected.